# Changing ImageButton margins in code

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Relative Layout with an ImageButton defined in xml. The image button has an attribute android:layout_marginBottom = "25dp".

Is it possible to change this attribute at run time, I want to move the button depending on screen size. I thought there would be a ImageButton.setMarginBottom method but it seems not. Another little inconsistency with android.

Comment: you can use setPadding function to set the padding for the image button or you can set the layout params for the button setLayoutParams

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, I am trying to come to terms with layout params right now. The concept seems rather complex and documentation is not so clear.

Comment: did u try the below answer provided ?

Comment: very close, about to make some small adjustments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.img_btn);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) imgBtn.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 25); //bottom margin is 25 here (change it as u wish)
imgBtn.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Kool4u, thanks, this is very close to what I found in another post. Although your .getLayoutParams() is likely to solve the issue I am currently having. I am feeling more confident now :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I reckon I have the issue sorted now. If you start with xml, you have to use .getLayoutParams() else you overwrite settings without knowing.